# Scripting the way firefox starts

Tags: windows, firefox, script, shell-script

In Windows 7, is there any way to script the websites that are opened whenever I open Firefox based on certain criteria?

For example, if it's Thursday, load a certain website as my homepage, but only on the first time Firefox is executed?

I've tried the Morning Coffee add-on, but it doesn't seem as versatile as a script could be. I'm guessing that any solution to this problem could also apply to other browsers too. I just don't know what language the script should be in, or how it would be called.